# Sum of roots of unity

Tags: co.combinatorics, sequences-and-series, roots-of-unity

Today I came across the series $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\varepsilon^{2k^2}$, where $\varepsilon$ is some primitive $n^\text{th}$ root of unity. Is there an explicit expression for this sum? I mistakenly introduced it with $k^2$ instead of $2k^2$ in wolframalpha (with the primitive root $e^{2i\pi/n}$) and it returned an [explicit expression](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=f%28n%29%3Dsum+from+k%3D0+to+n-1+of+e%5E%7B2*%CF%80*i*k%5E2%2Fn%7D), I'm not sure how to deduce it though.

For context in case this is an easy exercise in some branch of algebra, I am doing research in ergodic theory and these expressions appear when I compute some inner products using the rational eigenspaces of a unitary operator.

Comment: If $n$ is prime this seems reminiscent of Gauss sums: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_Gauss_sum

Comment: Oh, it seems they are the generalized quadratic Gauss sums from the wikipedia page you shared. Thanks!

Comment: @SaúlRM Isn't $\varepsilon$ the same as $\varepsilon^2$?

Comment: They are both primitive roots of unity (if n is odd at least), so the sum with exponents $2k^2$ can be obtained from the one with exponents $n^2$ if you know the second one for all roots of unity, if that is what you mean